# Topology on $[X]^2$ for Hausdorff space $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Hausdorff space. Let $[X]^2 = \big\{\{x,y\}: x,y\in X \land x\neq y\big\}$. For $U,V\in \tau$ with $U\cap V = \emptyset$ we set $[U,V] = \big\{\{x,y\} \in [X]^2: x\in U\land y\in V\big\}$.

On $[X]^2$ let $[\tau]^2$ be the topology generated by $\{[U,V]: U,V\in \tau\land U\cap V =\emptyset\}$.

For $X$ Hausdorff, is $([X]^2, [\tau]^2)$ also Hausdorff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\{ w , x \}, \{ y, z \} \in [X]^2$ are distinct. Then there are essentially two cases.

- $w,x,y,z$ are pairwise distinct.

  In this case take pairwise disjoint open neighborhoods $U_w, U_x, U_y, U_z$ for $w,x,y,z$, respectively, and note that $[ U_w , U_x ] \cap [ U_y , U_z ] = \emptyset$.
- $w = y$ and $x \neq z$.

  In this case take pairwise disjoint open neighborhoods $U_x , U_y , U_z$ for $x,y,z$, respectively, and note that $[ U_y , U_x ] \cap [ U_y , U_z ] = \emptyset$. (If $\{u,v\} \in [ U_y , U_x ] \cap [ U_y , U_z ]$ then without loss of generality $u \in U_y$, meaning that $v \in U_x \cap U_z = \emptyset$.)

(Note that if $X$ is a linearly ordered space — for example, the real line — then then $[X]^2$ is homeomorphic to the subspace $\{ (x,y) \in X \times X : x < y \}$ of $X \times X$, and so Hausdorffness of $[X]^2$ in this case is basically immediate.)